# Unable to subtract two time columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataset:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPAE1.jpg

I want to create a new column that is the subtraction between time_exit and time_entry.
However, when I try the code:

```
df[['tempo']] = df['time_exit'] - df['time_entry']
```

The result is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

If I do:

```
df[['tempo']] = df[['time_exit']] - df[['time_entry']]
```

The result is: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key.

But doing a describe on both, they have the SAME count, that is 381185.

I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the first error, your columns have the wrong datatype; you are trying to subtract a string from another. So, you should convert these columns:

```
df['time_exit'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_exit'])
df['time_entry'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_entry'])
```

then,

```
df['tempo'] = df['time_exit'] - df['time_entry']
```

should do the trick.

Your second approach fails, because `df[['time_exit']]` and `df[['time_entry']]` return DataFrames, rather than a Series.

Subtracting two DataFrames with one column each (and these columns have different names), returns a third dataframe, with two columns, filled with nan, which cannot be assigned to a single column.

Comment: I already when through this. 

Even adding the errors = coerce and format option arguments, the result is that every observation in the tempo column (which is created at least) is NaT.

Comment: alright, could you then post the head of the actual data as text, rather than image? check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for making good pandas examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` with `Timedelta`:

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['07:15:00', '08:00:00'], 'end':['08:15:00', '10:00:00']})

# apply with pd.Timedelta
df['diff'] = df['end'].apply(pd.Timedelta) - df['start'].apply(pd.Timedelta) 

      start       end     diff
0  07:15:00  08:15:00 01:00:00
1  08:00:00  10:00:00 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend specifying the format of the current time data first,

```
df['time_exit'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_exit'] , errors='coerce', format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', infer_datetime_format=True)
df['time_entry'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_entry'] , errors='coerce', format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', infer_datetime_format=True)
```

and after this :

```
df[['tempo']] = df['time_exit'] - df['time_entry']
```

If you need only the count of difference of days :

```
df[['tempo']] = (df['time_exit'] - df['time_entry']).dt.days
```